# How to clear cairo_region_t

Tags: cairo

I can't find a method that would clear all the rectangles from cairo_region_t. It seems possible to intersect the region with some nonexistent rectangle but isn't there a more direct approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see several possible approaches to clear a cairo_region_t:

- Just recreate it. :-P
- Get its extents via cairo_region_get_extents() and then pass that to cairo_region_subtract_rectangle().
- Use cairo_region_intersect() or cairo_region_intersect_rectangle() to intersect it with an empty rectangle/region.